# How data will be stored to primary after the crash in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-partitioning

I'm newbie to HBase. Assume that we have master and secondary regions.

Just assume that our primary region goes down for few hours due to some external factors. if the primary server is turned back to normal status.

It might have missed some amount of data loaded during the primary region offline. So how the primary server will be synchronized to load missed jobs.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If primary region server crashes or becomes unavailable, secondary region server will  provide read-only access to the data. Primary region server provides both write/read access but secondary region server provides only read access.
[See this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12616659/HighAvailabilityDesignforreadsApachedoc.pdf)

Regarding data recovery, data is written in WAL (Write-Ahread-Log) before actual write, when region server recovers all the pending logs will be replayed and node will be in sync.